# Leave "VISUAL mode" in Vi

Tags: vim

I'm starting a new project and I have a problem. In a new Vi file, where it is supposed to say `INSERT`, it shows `VISUAL`. Can anyone explain me how  I may leave the `VISUAL` mode?

Answer (score 3):

You have entered (charcater) visual mode, probably by pressing <kbd>v</kbd> in command/normal mode.  Visual mode  is a mode in which the Vim (not Vi) editor allows you to select text, either by character, by line, or by block (you may then perform various actions on the selected text).

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> would exit this mode and return you command/normal mode. You may also type <kbd>v</kbd> in character visual mode to leave this mode.

See also `:help visual-mode` in Vim (or [on the vimdoc site](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd> button and you will exit the Visual Mode. Then enter the mode you want to!

Answer (score 0):

You entered visual mode, meant to highlight, copy, paste, etc. Press `v` again or `ESC` to exit. `ESC` will exit *almost* any mode in Vim if you run into trouble again!